# How do you make a variable within a function as global in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have just started learning about TKinter but have been getting stuck in a certain part of my project for quite a while. I want to accept a username and password from the user.
If it already exists, I want to display a message box with an error message. And if isn't, I want the program to able to store those values so that includes it the next time it is assessing whether the username and password exist.

I have been able to do as much:

```
usernames=['Arya']
passwords=['mynameisarya']
def clicked():
    count=0
    count1=0
    if e4.get() in usernames:
        count+=1
    if e5.get() in passwords:
        count1+=1
    if count!=0:
        messagebox.showinfo('Problem', 'Username Already in Use')
    if count1!=0:
        messagebox.showinfo('Problem','Password Already in Use')
    
    global count2
    count2=count+count1
    if count2==0:
        messagebox.showinfo('Congrats','Successfully Registered')

    
    
    
highlight=Label(RPage, text='REGISTRATION FORM', font=('@HP Simplified Japn',14),fg='black',bg='white')
highlight.place(x=125,y=50)

fname=Label(RPage, text='First Name', font=('@HP Simplified Japn',11),fg='black',bg='white')
fname.place(x=125,y=100)
e1=Entry(RPage)
e1.place(x=200, y=100)

lname=Label(RPage, text='Last Name', font=('@HP Simplified Japn',11),fg='black',bg='white')
lname.place(x=125,y=150)
e2=Entry(RPage)
e2.place(x=200, y=150)

email=Label(RPage, text='Email Address', font=('@HP Simplified Japn',11),fg='black',bg='white')
email.place(x=100,y=200)
e3=Entry(RPage)
e3.place(x=200, y=200)

username=Label(RPage, text='Username', font=('@HP Simplified Japn',11),fg='black',bg='white')
username.place(x=125,y=250)
e4=Entry(RPage)
e4.place(x=200, y=250)
e4.bind('<Return>', clicked)



password=Label(RPage, text='Password', font=('@HP Simplified Japn',11),fg='black',bg='white')
password.place(x=125,y=300)
e5=Entry(RPage)
e5.place(x=200, y=300)
e5.bind('<Return>',clicked)

submit=Button(RPage, text='SUBMIT', font=('@HP Simplified Japn',12),fg='black',bg='white', command=clicked)
submit.place(x=160,y=350)
```

However, I get an error saying that the variable must be defined before using it. Essentially, what I was trying to do is if count2==0, appending the username and password entered into the list in such a way that the list is appended throughout, not just within the function.
It would be great if you could help :)

EDIT - The exact line causing the error is:

```
global count2
count2=count+count1
if count2==0:
 messagebox.showinfo('Congrats','Successfully Registered')
```

I get an error saying that count is not defined.

Comment: Please add the code that was causing the error to that in your question.

Comment: Use `global username, password` in the beginning and then add `usernames.append(e4.get())`,`passwords.append(e5.get())` in your condition.

Comment: @martineau the code line was global count2
    count2=count+count1
    if count2==0:
        messagebox.showinfo('Congrats','Successfully Registered')

Comment: @AST Ohh... Thanks! I'll try it out!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code to it — it's very difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: @martineau done.. please check the edit at the end of the question